A specification of all possible languages for representing graphs?
There are a few commonly used markup languages for specifying graph structures.
I am interested in discovering alternative graph notations that may be counterintuitive yet more compact or useful in some way.
Assuming a program is an ordered sequence of symbols, I feel like the question is about how many different ways the data of a graph can be “linearized”.
In set theory, a (directed) graph is an ordered pair consisting of a set called Nodes, and a set called Edges, where Edges are ordered pairs taking values from Nodes.
I’m wondering if there’s a clear mathematical treatment of this or any reference materials to study.
I feel like the next step in developing this question should be determining constraints on what the data can exclude. If we assume that this program can reconstruct any possible (finite) graph, we can prove that it would not work if our “encoding” mapped every graph structure into an empty string.
I am picturing some sort of diagram where the set-theoretic description of a particular graph is mapped to a particular sequence (of symbols, which can be represented as arbitrary distinct sets); we want to study the class of such mappings to explore interesting properties that different maps (essentially, encodings) have.
I feel like category theory would be relevant to this.

I can't understand what you are asking.  What exactly is your question?  Please articulate one, specific question in your post.  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to formulate a specific question -- don't force us to guess.  A question normally ends with "?".  I don't know what you mean by "a clear mathematical treatment of this" (what precisely does "this" refer to?).

It sounds like you are not sure quite what question to ask yet, and as such, it seems premature to post on this site.  This site is a place where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge, in the format of questions and answers.  Open-ended unclear posts that set a topic but don't have a specific question usually aren't a good fit for this site's format.

Are you asking about graph6/sparse6 file format?
